# Windows Azure table storage limit is about 500 rps

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Windows Azure table storage limit is about 500 requests per second, more requests than this and a DoS is supected and you will get error messages.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikekelly/archive/2010/04/06/windows-azure-panel-discussion-q-a.aspx

My application average CRUD operation takes 100 milliseconds, that is 10 per second. If I set my connection limit to 50,

```
<connectionManagement>
  <!-- See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/d84ba34b-b0e0-4961-a167-bbe7618beb83 -->
  <add address="*" maxconnection="50" />
</connectionManagement>
```

then I will easily reach the Windows Azure table storage request limit with just one instance at peak times.

My question is; **is there a way to increase the Windows Azure table storage request limit?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because it's not a threshold for detecting a DoS attack; it's the scalability limit of the service.

But do read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx for the full details on scalability targets. 500 per second is against a single table storage partition. It's 5,000 per second for the entire storage account.